# Is there any way to add an HTTP Header to every IE request on a computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, batch-file

I would like to add a custom HTTP Header to every Internet Explorer request on a computer (or every browser request). I don't know if this is possible whatsoever, if you have heard of anyway to accomplish such a task, could you please point me in a general direction?

I've thought about opening IE with a PowerShell wrapper, or editing the registry but can't find out if headers can be modified that way.  I'm open to whatever options may be available but I'm coming up short in a way to achieve this.  Thank you!

I apologize if this is the wrong place for this question and I appreciate any guidance or ideas whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible.  I found `Customize user agent` string in the Internet Explorer section of the Group Policy Management Editor. Specifically modifying the Post Platform section meetings my needs.